# Простая реализация паттерна Singletone на c#

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Разбираюсь сейчас Singletone, нашел в сети несколько разных реализаций, но так и не понял, как они работают. Синглтон - это паттерн, который гарантирует наличие только одного экземпляра класса, а в примерах я немного не понимаю, как эта "гарантия" реализуется.
Первый пример

```
public sealed class MySingleton  {  
static MySingleton myInstance = null;  

MySingleton()  
{  
}  

public static MySingleton MyInstance  
{  
    get  
    {  
        if (myInstance = = null)  
        {  
            myIinstance = new MySingleton();  
        }  
        return myInstance;  
    }  
    private set;  
    }
}
```

Второй пример:

```
class Singleton
{  
   static Singleton obj;    
   public static Singleton Obj { get { return obj; } }   
   public string Data { get; set; }     
   static Singleton()  
   {  
      obj = new Singleton();  
   }    
   private Singleton()  
   {
      Data = "I am a singleton";  
   }
}

//вызов
{  
   static void Main(string[] args)   
   {  
      Singleton s1 = Singleton.Obj;  
      Console.WriteLine(s1.Data);   
   }
}
```

Собственно, можете объяснить чем эти два примера отличается друг от друга, и как они гарантируют наличие одного экземпляра класса? Или они оба неправильны, и есть более простая и понятная реализации паттерна на c#?

Comment: А Вы попробуйте создать 2 экземпляра из того кода, что у Вас есть. Когда не получится, к Вам должно прийти понимание того, почему этот код гарантирует один экземпляр.

Comment: @ixSci, для первого варианта, кстати, может и получиться

Comment: @Grundy, ну если несколько потоков, то получается data race и два могут быть созданы, но в результате всё равно останется только один.

Comment: _"есть более простая и понятная реализации паттерна на c#?"_ -- есть `public class Data { public static readonly Data Instance = new Data(); private Data() { } }`

Answer (score 5):

Гарантия реализуется за счет того, что класс `Singleton` не предоставляет никаких других способов получения экземпляра, кроме статического свойства - а свойство написано так, что двух разных экземпляров никогда не отдаст.

Обратите внимание на приватный конструктор - для синглтонов это очень важно.

Отличие между приведенными примерами в том, что первый вариант создает экземпляр по требованию - второй же создает свой экземпляр при инициализации класса. Вообще говоря, так как инициализация класса в .NET, в свою очередь, также происходит по требованию - различие тут не очень-то и велико.

Еще если отличия в потокобезопасности - для статических конструкторов потокобезопасность гарантируется средой, а вот первый вариант синглтона может работать только в однопоточной среде.

По поводу простых примеров - вот так синглтоны обычно пишу я:

```
public class Foo {
  private Foo() { }
  public static readonly Foo INSTANCE = new Foo();

  // ...
}
```

По сути, это второй вариант - но выглядит он куда проще. Тут просто создается неизменяемая статическая переменная, и ничего больше.

### PS

Современные тенденции - избегать синглтонов; не следует делать синглтонами все подряд. Перед тем как некоторый класс сделать синглтоном, задумайтесь: а что страшного случится если кто-то (возможно, вы сами) создаст второй экземпляр этого класса? В большинстве случаев, ответ - "да ничего не случится". Если это так - не надо делать класс синглтоном.

Answer (score 5):

Примеры синглтонов, которые используются в .NET Framework,
можно посмотреть в [исходниках .NET Framework](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=singleton)

Простая реализация синглтона:

```
public class Data { 
  public static readonly Data Instance = new Data(); 
  private Data() { 
  } 
}
```

---

Если Data - это большой объект, и его надо создавать по-требованию, то можно использовать `Lazy<T>`

```
public class Data { 
  static readonly Data _Instance = 
         new Lazy<Data>(() => new Data(), 
         LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly); 
  public static Data Instance { get { return _Instance.Value; }}
  private Data() { 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Простая реализация - использование `Lazy<T>`. Как раз именно с `Lazy` задумываться над всеми этими многопоточными реализациями уже не приходится, работает из коробки. [Код отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6847882/3768545):

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> instanceHolder =
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

    private Singleton()
    {
        ...
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get { return instanceHolder.Value; }
    }
}
```

Я под синглтон использую обычно класс настроек программы. Ну т.е. у них есть метод Save и куча полей, которые мне нужны в рантайме. Если вдруг когда то мне захочется добавить профили настроек - достаточно расшить точку `Instance`, а не переписывать абсолютно все обращения к настройкам в коде, в этом преимущество.

Разница со статик классами небольшая, но мне например в статик классах постоянно мешает то, что расшивать их обычно очень неудобно. Плюс, хранить два экземпляра статик класса в качестве двух профилей настроек уже не получится. Тогда как тупая сериализация инстанса - вполне рабочее решение.