# Как обновить данные в объекте-одиночке?

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть объект, созданный по паттерну "Одиночка".
Как можно, например, один раз в сутки сделать так, чтобы он сам обновлял в себе данные?

```
class PilotRecipients
  {
      private static PilotRecipients _instance;
      private static List<string> _recipientList;
      private static string ConnectionString;

      private PilotRecipients() { }

      public static PilotRecipients GetInstance()
      {
          if (_instance == null)
          {
              _instance = new PilotRecipients();
              _recipientList = new List<string>();

              //строка подключения
              ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConnection"];
              //сформируем список получателей
              GetRecipientList();
          }
          return _instance;

      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Проверка получателя в пилотном списке
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="key"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public bool CheckRecipient(string key)
      {
          if (_recipientList.Contains(key))
          {
              return true;
          }
          else
          {
              return false;
          }
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Формирование пилотного спсика получателей
      /// </summary>
      static void GetRecipientList()
      {
          DataTable dt = new DataTable();

          using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
          {
              conn.Open();

              using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[proc_GetSmtpPilotRecipients]", conn))
              {
                  cmd.Connection = conn;
                  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                  using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                  {
                      da.Fill(dt);
                  }
              }
          }

          //заполняем список получателей
          for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
          {
              _recipientList.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
          }

      }
  }
```

Comment: А как бы Вы сделали это не в «одиночке»?

Comment: А почему бы не использовать какой-либо внешний таймер, который раз в сутки инициирует обновление данных в "одиночке"?)

Comment: там где создается объект, запускаете таймер, с интервалом на сутки. другой вариант: вместе с объектом, рядом сохраняете DateTime.Now, а при обращении за объектом проверяете разницу между текущим DateTime и сохраненным и создаете новый объект.

Comment: @Stack, В том-то и тонкость, что одиночка создает сам себя

Comment: @DmitriySimushev так можно поле в одиночке добавить, LastUpdate к примеру. И на каждый гет инстанса - проверять, не прошли ли сутки. Если прошли - обновлять данные.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev _"В том-то и тонкость, что одиночка создает сам себя"_ -- да. но доступ к нему происходит через свойство, например, `public static Data Instance { get { ... }}` - см. [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486519/196972). в get может быть проверка даты и т.д.

Comment: Проверять дату в Instance get может оказаться недостаточно, если ссылка на Instance берётся единожды и хранится, а обращение к методу или свойству происходит через неделю после этого.