# Область видимости классов C#. Запрет создания объектов

Tags: c#, namespace

Имеем несколько незначительно различающихся классов

```
class A{} class B{}
```

имеем **Generic**, который является коллекцией объектов вышеперечисленных классов

```
class Gen<T>{}
```

коллекции `Gen<A>` и `Gen<B>` должны существовать в единственном экземпляре. Если я правильно понял документацию, синглтон из дженерика сделать нельзя. Для контроля над созданием коллекций применяем что-то вроде фабричного метода:

```
class CollectionManager{
  private static readonly CollectionManager _manager = new CollectionManager();
  private CollectionManager(){};
  public static CM {get {return _manager; }}

  private static Gen<A> _genA = new Gen<A>();
  private static Gen<B> _genB = new Gen<B>();

  public Gen<A> GenA { get { return _genA; }}
  .........
}
```

А теперь вопрос: как из кода программы запретить явное создание `Gen<A>`? Т.е. сделать так, чтобы инстанс `Gen<A>` можно было бы получить только из `CollectionManager`, а `new Gen<A>()` в остальном коде запретить.

Comment: делай приватный конструктор. А где читал что _синглтон из дженерика сделать нельзя_?

Comment: Синглтон из дженерика сделать можно, как и из любого другого класса.

Comment: а пример можно? не соображу

Comment: У вас прямо в вопросе и есть два синглтона. И даже синглтон с определением прямо в `Gen<T>` вполне сделать можно

Comment: по большому счету синглтон это класс с приватным конструктором и одним публичным свойством, например instance, которое заполняется один раз

Comment: @PashaPash, а я только один вижу, а остальные где?

Comment: @Grundy _genA и _genB - синглтоны. Просто свойство для доставания _genB скрыто в .....

Comment: так, т.е. private static Gen<T> _gen = new Gen<T>() допускается? и return _gen вернет разные рефы для каждого T?

Comment: @PashaPash, аааа, я просто под снглтоном полностью класс думал, а тут свойства, но да принцип такой же :)

Comment: @ivan_n3786330, достаточно просто попробовать чтобы узнать :-)

Comment: @ivan_n3786330 хм, внезапно, допускается :)

Comment: всем огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот пример простой реализации

```
class A { }
class B { }
public class Gen<T> where T : class
{
    private static Gen<T> _instance;
    protected Gen() { }
    public static Gen<T> Instance
    {
        get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new Gen<T>()); }
    }
}
```

Делаем защищённый конструктор, приватную статическую переменную для хранения нашего единственного экземпляра и свойство (метод) доступа к нему.

Вот пример вызова

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Успешное создание путём к обращению свойства синглтона
        var trueGenCreation = Gen<A>.Instance; 
        // Попытка обращения к защищённому конструкторц
        var wrongGenCreation = new Gen<A>();
    }
}
```

**P.S.** Как заметили в комментариях, данная реализация не является потокобезопасной и можно использовать вариант  [со статическим конструктором](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486507/18407) или [с использованием класса Lazy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486513/18407).

Comment: Это не потокобезопасная реализация. Стоит взять реализацию вроде http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486507/177221 - вида `public static readonly Foo INSTANCE = new Foo();`. она тоже ленивая, но без проблем с потоками.

Comment: Или вместо проблемного велосипеда применить `Lazy<T>` явным образом: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx#lazy

Comment: @PashaPash можете объяснить, за счёт чего достигается ленивость в указанной вами реализации? потокобезопасность, насколько я понял будет гарантироваться статическим конструктором.

Comment: @beta-tank: Ленивость за счёт того же. В C# статические конструкторы выполняются не энергично, а при первом доступе к типу.

Comment: И кстати, реализация из википедии с рефлексией ужасна.

Comment: @VladD спасибо за объяснения. Таким образом, пытаясь ответить на вопрос сам узнал что-то новое =)

Comment: @beta-tank: Пожалуйста! И кстати, почитайте статью из второго комментария, она стоит того.