# Как найти лишний поток?

Tags: c#, windows, sql-server

Создал приложение, которое с периодичностью 5 минут проверяет обновления на сервере. Приложение можно запустить только одно на локальной машине, контролирую через mutex:

```
instanceMutex = new Mutex(true, @"Global\" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType().GUID.ToString(), out createdNew); //Local
        if (!createdNew)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("1mf-alno Updater запущена у другого пользователя. Нельзя запускать две копии 1mf-alno Updater на одном компьютере. Обновления для вас не доступны.");
            instanceMutex = null;
            Current.Shutdown();
            return;
        }
```

Класс, который проверяет обновления сделан через патерн синглтон, весь его код не буду выкладывать, только конструктор с реализацией синглтона:

```
private static FPTClass instance;

    public static FPTClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new FPTClass(host, user, pass);
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }    

private FPTClass(string hostIP, string userName, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            //отдельный поток для progressBar
            worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
            worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;

            string catalogUpd = "";
            using (wiupDataContext dcUser = new wiupDataContext())
            {
                catalogUpd = dcUser.RegKeys.FirstOrDefault(x => x.key == SingleApp.superpro.serialNum).catalog.Trim();
            }

            host = hostIP + catalogUpd + "/";
            user = userName;
            pass = password;

            //запускаем таймер проверки обновления на сервере ftp
            timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (processing || !isOk)
                    return;
                processing = true;
                try
                {
                    if (ftpResponse != null)
                    {
                        //на всякий случай
                        ftpResponse.Close();
                        ftpRequest = null;
                    }

                    checkNewCatalog();
                    processing = false;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    SingleApp.notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip("Ошибка обновления каталога.", ex.Message, BalloonIcon.Error);
                    processing = false;
                }
            };
            timer.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            SingleApp.utilityClass.ДобавитьЗаписьВЛог(e, "tNgStN");
        }
    }
```

В процессе обновления возникает ошибка, которая фиксируется на SQL Server'е, причина ошибки понятна, но по скрину видно, что запись дублируется, т.е. в момент возникновения ошибки было 2 потока, которые вызвали этот код почти одновременно, почему так происходит? Где образуется второй поток? Как можно отследить это?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите код, который бросает ошибку. Судя по тексту исключения - вы где-то вызываете Single/SingleOrDefault. В приведенном вами коде этого вызова нет.

Comment: да, всё верно, я в курсе, что у меня более одной записи в таблице, хотя пытаюсь выполнить следующий код: PendingUpd curRec = pendUpd.Single(); проблема не в этом, проблема в двух потоках, которых не должно быть, всегда должен быть только один

Comment: Если честно - я не понимаю, какое отношение `pendUpd.Single()` имеет отношение к коду в вопросе. Насклько я понял - почти никакого. Вопрос должен содержать [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @PashaPash, вы правы эта строка совершенно никаким образом не относиться к моей проблеме, и возникающая ошибка тоже, моя проблема состоит в том что у меня создаётся лишний поток, хотя я вроде всё предусмотрел и учёл, но он есть и это видно по скрину, как мне можно найти этот поток? может я не правильно оформил синглтон или mutex? код я выложил выше

Comment: Ниже был дан ответ (скорее всего правильный, не уверен почему автор его удалил) - у вас непотокобезопасная реализация Singleton. Перепишите его на потокобезопасную (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486519/177221, вариант со static readonly). Если не поможет - значит проблема в другом месте :(