# Происходит запуск 4 браузеров но действия происходят только в 2

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, nunit

Что бы использовать один тест для двух браузеров написал отдельную переменную которая хранит массив браузеров

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace InputAndClickInBrowsers
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestsWithMultipleBrowsers
    {
```

Код в теле класса.

```
 static IWebDriver[] DriversForCase =
        {
            ChromeInitialization.Instanse,
            FireFoxInitialization.Instanse
        };
```

далее передал этот пассив в тест

```
[TestCaseSource(nameof(DriversForCase))]
        public void GoToBbcCom_ReturnedSearchFieldStatus(IWebDriver _driver)
        {
            _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.bbc.com/");

            var textForSearch = "this";
            //Close pop-up window            
            _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='sign_in-exit']")).Click();

            //Find string for search            
            var bbcSearchInput = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[placeholder='Search']"));
            if (bbcSearchInput.Displayed && bbcSearchInput.Enabled)
            {
                bbcSearchInput.Click();
            }

            //Writing some text to search
            bbcSearchInput.SendKeys(textForSearch);

            // Click button for starting Search
            _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@id='orb-search-button']")).Click();
            var textInCurrentSearchLine = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input")).GetAttribute("value");
            var firstUrl = _driver.Url;

            //Click first link             
            _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class='css-vh7bxp-PromoLink e1f5wbog6'][1]")).Click();
            var urlOfNewPage = _driver.Url;

            Assert.IsTrue(textForSearch == textInCurrentSearchLine);
            Assert.AreEqual(urlOfNewPage, _driver.Url);
        }
```

и все как бы работает не нужно писать лишние тесты для других браузеров по необходимости можно просто изменить массив. Но вопрос в следующем при начале выполнения кода или на этапе сборки открываются 2 браузера но в дальнейшем не используются. И потом при выполнении теста открывается еще 2 браузера и в них уже выполняются шаги теста. В чем проблема почему так выходит. И как можно исправить это в коде.

реализация ChromeInitialization и ChromeInitialization одинаковы поэтому закину код одного из данных классов.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace InputAndClickInBrowsers
{
    public class ChromeInitialization
    {
        //- Инициализация браузера — применить паттерн синглтон для инициализации браузера   

        private static ChromeInitialization _classObject;
        private static ChromeDriver _chrome;

        private ChromeInitialization() { }

        public static ChromeDriver Instanse
        {
            get
            {
                if (_classObject == null)
                {
                    _classObject = new ChromeInitialization();
                    _chrome = new ChromeDriver();
                }
                 return _chrome;                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `ChromeInitialization.Instanse` и `FireFoxInitialization.Instanse` на `new ChromeDriver()` и `new FirefoxDriver()` соответственно

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Вы же не видите кода, может там статика два раза инициализируется!

Comment: ну у вас два раза инициализируется каждый браузер.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko пробовал не помогает. Все равно открывается 2 браузера а потом еще 2 в которых уже выполняется тестовые шаги.

Comment: @YuryBakharev хорошо даже если 2 инициализации запуск самих тестовых шагов только в двух браузерах остальные просто открыты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вроде вот так, открываются только два. Может конечно не так удобно тестировать, как хочет автор. Но вроде на браузерах сценарий идёт асинхронно сразу на 2-х и ничего не открывается лишнего. Почему это происходит, не разбирался.

```
 public class Test
{
    static IWebDriver[] _driversForCase;

    public async Task RunTest()
    {
       var test = new Test();
       await test.TestDrivers();          
    }

    public async Task TestDrivers()
    {
        foreach (IWebDriver webDriver in GetWebDrivers())
        {
            await Task.Run(() => GoToBbcCom_ReturnedSearchFieldStatus(webDriver));
        }
    }


    protected IWebDriver[] GetWebDrivers()
    {
        if (_driversForCase == null)
            _driversForCase = new IWebDriver[] { new ChromeDriver(), new OperaDriver() };
        return _driversForCase;
    }


    protected  void GoToBbcCom_ReturnedSearchFieldStatus(IWebDriver _driver)
    {
       //_driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.bbc.com/");

        var textForSearch = "this";
        //Close pop-up window            
        _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='sign_in-exit']")).Click();

        //Find string for search            
        var bbcSearchInput = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[placeholder='Search']"));
        if (bbcSearchInput.Displayed && bbcSearchInput.Enabled)
        {
            bbcSearchInput.Click();
        }

        //Writing some text to search
        bbcSearchInput.SendKeys(textForSearch);

        // Click button for starting Search
        _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@id='orb-search-button']")).Click();
        var textInCurrentSearchLine = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input")).GetAttribute("value");
        var firstUrl = _driver.Url;

        //Click first link             
        _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class='css-vh7bxp-PromoLink e1f5wbog6'][1]")).Click();
        var urlOfNewPage = _driver.Url;
    }
}
```

И вызвать это

```
Test t = new Test();
        t.TestDrivers();
        Thread.Sleep(30000);// Можно любое число поставить;)
```

В коде который вы выслали у вас два раза инициализируется браузер

```
  public class ChromeInitialization
{

    private static ChromeDriver _classObject;

    private ChromeInitialization() { }

    public static ChromeDriver Instanse
    {
        get
        {
            if (_classObject == null)
                _classObject = new ChromeDriver();
            return _classObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот так попробуйте.

Comment: А куда вы дели самое главное - выражения `Assert`? Т.е. ваш код выполняет действия, но он ничего не проверяет, правильно я понимаю?

Comment: И вы не ответили на вопрос автора `почему так происходит`

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Я предоставил вариант как это можно исправить, не более. То что внутри сценария не имеет отношение к вопросу, о том что открываются 4 браузера вместо 2-х.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko чтобы понять, почему так происходит, нужно увидеть код автора. проблема точно не коде из вопроса :)

Comment: Добавил часть кода которая может быть сможет помочь в ответе на массовый запуск брауеров.

Comment: @ПавелПанасюк посмотрите в конец ответа, кажется это то что вам нужно, ну или хотя-бы указание на проблему.

Comment: @aepot оно вроде как указание. Но там код не рабочий сам по себе. Но попробую что то поменять.

Comment: @Павел Панасюк Где не рабочий код?

Comment: @YuryBakharev  _classObject = new ChromeDriver(); тут нельзя привести класс ChromeInitialization к ChromeDriver ну и вот здесь _classObject = new ChromeInitialization(); тоже получается что обратно пытаемся привести все. В общем Upcast и Downcast не проходят в этом случае. Но главное, что Ваш код все же помог мне найти и решить проблему!

Comment: @ПавелПанасюк, извиняюсь, с телефона писал. Поправил в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

В общем исходя из всех советов реализовал по другому классы по инициализации драйвера.
Вот так получилось насколько я понимаю паттерн Singleton остался соблюден так как проверял HashCode у разных объектов класса он одинаковый. Может быть кому то в дальнейшем поможет.

```
public class ChromeInitialization
    {
        //- Инициализация браузера — прменить паттерн синглтон для инициализации браузера   

        private static ChromeDriver _classObject;

        private ChromeInitialization() { }

        public static ChromeDriver Instanse
        {
            get
            {
                if (_classObject == null)
                    _classObject = new ChromeDriver();
                return _classObject;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instanse - исправьте на Instanсe :)

Comment: Насчет реализации Singleton - есть стандартное решение в одну строку - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486507/177221